# for loop in a for loop not applying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have 2 arrays these arrays hold object values in them:

-VariantArry which has 26 arrays in there.

-ProductArray which has 6 arrays in there

Now each have a id which will match so for example `ProductArray[1].Id = 10029`
now this be able to match within the VariantArray so for example within the VariantArray there is something in there called `VariantArray[1].Product.Id`.

Now if they match i want to push it in a array having the ProductArray and VariantArray in there. Now that all works fine my problem is i end up with a array length of 23.. i want all the ids which match to be in the same array so i should end up with 6 arrays all having all the variants which match the product ID.. at the moment its creating a new array for each.

i.e

NewArray[1].Product (holds my product data)

NewArray[1].Variant[6] (holds all my variants in another array)

Javascript code:

```
                var NewArray = [];
                var p;
                var va;
                for (va = 0; va < VariantArray.length; va++) {
                    for (p = 0; p < ProductArray.length; p++) { 
                    if (ProductArray[p].Id == VariantArray[va].Product.Id)
                    {
                        NewArray.push({ Product: ProductArray[p], Variants: VariantArray[va] });
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Any help in a better way for this to work properly?
Thanks
Dom

Comment: Those are standard `for` loops.

Comment: If something has a property like `ProductId` or `Id` then it can’t be a simple array but a JavaScript object. If you’d tell us the actual structure of your arrays we could provide better help.

Comment: variable p can be global if you have not explicitly declared with "var p = 0". 
I have faced this problem. Make sure you have declared all the variable properly with in its scope.

Comment: All it holds is IDs like i have explained above. and i have declared var p etc

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
var NewArray = [];
            for (p = 0; p < ProductArray.length; p++) { 
               for (va = 0; va < VariantArray.length; va++) {
                if (ProductArray[p].Id == VariantArray[va].Product.Id)
                {
                    NewArray.push({ Product: ProductArray[p], Variants: VariantArray[va] });
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
```

Put the inner loop outside and put break in inner loop when you find id.

Comment: If i do that not all my variants get pushed in the array.. yes that gives me a array of 6 but i have missed out on most of my variants

Comment: can you elaborate the question with some example. I am not getting what do you want exactly. Example will be a help.

Answer (score 0):

Here a more elaborated code, I coded on the fly. Hope it's useful for your purpose.

```
var NewArray = [];
for (var p = 0; p < ProductArray.length; p++) { 
    for (var va = 0; va < VariantArray.length; va++) {
        if (ProductArray[p].Id == VariantArray[va].Product.Id)
        {
            addVariant(NewArray, ProductArray[p], VariantArray[va]);
        }
    }
}

/**
* Finds the index of the product in the array
*/
function getProductIndex(array, productId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].Product.Id == productId) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
* Appends the variant if the product exists in the array. If not, it creates a new element for the given product and appends the variant.
*/
function addVariant(array, product, variant) {
    var index = getProductIndex(array, product.Id);
    if (index == -1) {
        var variants = [];
        variants.push(variant);
        array.push({Product: product, Variants: variants});
    }
    else {
        array[index].Variants.push(variant);
    }
}
```

Comment: No this doesnt work.. i want to get ALL the variants which match the product in the same array like i have explained above

Comment: this si pushing the product EACH TIME and the variant in seperate arrays, it needs to only have 1 product in the array and multiple variants?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the call of getProductIndex, edited. It's correct for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductArray.forEach(function (product) {
    results.push({
        product: product,
        variants: ProductArray.filter(function (variant) {
            return variant.productId == product.productId
        })
    })
})
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/60rk1219/
Note: example has a slightly different code because the author edited the question after the fiddle was saved.

In your code, you try matching each element of the `VariantArray` with each element of the `ProductArray` and for each match you find you put a value `NewArray`. This way you get an entry for each match.

To build an object that contains each product with all the respective variants you can loop through the `ProductArray` and find the matching entries in `VariantArray`.